# What are the least and most turbulent hours of the day?

Tags: weather, turbulence

Yes, it is quieter on the early morning, but what about the other hours of the 24 hours of the day?

I want to know statistically which hours of the day are the most and least turbulent, is there any data?

*PS: This question excludes wake turbulence type.*

Comment: Well It depends on length of day but basically you are going to be looking at mid-afternoon as the most turbulent.  But you are asking about data so this isn't really an answer.

Comment: At low levels, convective turbulence is at its lowest early in the morning and late in the afternoon/evening when the Sun's heat is weak.  Mid-afternoon, when the surface has heated-up ("two o 'clock thermals") is worst.  But there's also mechanical turbulence from winds converging or passing over terrain, they don't usually depend on the time of day.